# Trying to build a queue using linked list in c++ but got this error:

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes

I just started learning c++ and I am working on an assignment asking us to build queue using linked list, but when I tried my "display function" I got an `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` error, my logic behind this function is that little arrow(->) is to dereference pointers, so in theory it should be able to print out the data inside the node. Could anyone tell me what is the issue with my code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

node *front, *last, *use;

bool isempty(){
    if(front == NULL)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
void add(int a){
    node *t = new node;
    t->data = a;
    if(isempty()==false){
        front = t;
        last = t;
    }else{
        front = front->next;
        t->next = front;
        front = t;
    }
    
}

void goaway(){
    if(isempty()==true){
        use = front;
        do{
            last = use;
            use = use->next;
        }while(use->next!=NULL);
        if(use->next == NULL)
            cout<<"You just delete: "<<use->data<<endl;
            delete use;
    }
    else{
    cout<<"Nothing in here. "<<endl;
    }
}

void display(){
    cout<<"Your stored element: "<<endl;
    for (use = front; use!=NULL; use = use->next) {
        cout<<use->data;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

int main(){
    front= NULL;
    last = NULL;
    int flag = 1;
    while(flag == 1){
        int choice;
        cout<<"1 add 2 remove 3 display 4 exit"<<endl;
        cin>>choice;
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            int a;
            cout<<"Input element!"<<endl;
            cin>>a;
            add(a);
            break;
        case 2:
            goaway();
            break;
        case 3:
            display();
            break;
        case 4:
            flag = 2;
        default:
            cout<<"wrong choice!!"<<endl;
            flag = 3;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to "build queue using linked list" you should use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list and impress your teacher with efficiency.

Comment: I get confused by the implementation of `isempty()`. It has inverted logic. A NULL front pointer gets you "it is not empty" as an answer. Luckily or unluckily you also misuse it correspondingly...

Comment: After `t->data = a;` you fail to initialize `t->next = NULL;` (or to `nullptr` -- your choice)  Then when you iterate, e.g. `while(use->next!=NULL)` your `->next` pointer at the end isn't `NULL` so you invoke Undefined Behavior as you continue attempting to read past the end of your list resulting in `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: Instead of having a bunch of global variables, write a proper `queue` class. Now you are trying to add elements at the front of the list and retrieving elements from the tail (looping), consider storing the `last` pointer to the tail of the list and adding the elements to said tail while removing the elements from the front.

Comment: @Yunnosch, thank you! I'll look into it, and you're right, hahaha it's inverted I should change that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, oh right, I got it now, thank you so much! I spent hours trying to fix it!

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, I realized that I wasn't 100% clear on the concept of front and tail and got them mixed up, yeah It seems like at that time I was trying to add new nodes to the front instead of the tail because at that time I thought the front should be the one accepting new pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, In `else block` of `add` function, I don't understand why are you incrementing `front` while adding new Node. By doing `front = front->next` your front pointer always points to second node in the list whenever you call add function and your first node get waste every time which results `no nodes in the list`.

Secondly, In your `add` function, after `t->data = a;` you did not initialize `t->next = NULL` that's why you are facing undefined behavior.

Your add function should be like this:

```
void add(int a) {
    node* t = new node;
    t->data = a;
    t->next = NULL;
    if (isempty() == false) {
        front = t;
        last = t;
    }
    else {
        t->next = front;
        front = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg you're right, after you pointing that out I have no idea why I wrote the add function in that way, thank you! I guess I got confused when I was trying to understand what pointer and node do.